# TinyMCE toolbar options based on the editor's width

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

Is there a way to set the toolbar items in TinyMCE based on the editor's width?
So What I want is to set the toolbar prop conditionally, something like this:

```
const mobileToolbar = ['bold', 'italic', 'underline']
const desktopToolbar = ['redo', 'undo', 'bold', 'italic']

<Editor
   toolbar={ width < 1024 ? mobileToolbar : desktopToolbar }
```

I know there is a `mobile` option on the `init` object. But that only works on actual mobile devices, not if the screen size is smaller than a certain number of px.

By the way, I'm using React, so if someone has a working solution, please provide it.